# Create a multiply input and proceed with the division

Tags: javascript, math, input, arithmetic-expressions, multiplication

I'm a beginner in javascript, I want to create an input that follows a formula,

> *(Cell count/Volume) x Dilution*
>
> *Volume = length x width x height*

I've tried with the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Cell Count</title> 
</head>
<body>
<form>
Cell Count : <input type="text" id="cell-count" /><br>
Box Count : <input type="text" id="box-count" /><br>
Dilution : <input type="text" id="dilution" /><br>
Length : <input type="text" id="lgh" /><br>
Width : <input type="text" id="wdh" /><br>
Height : <input type="text" Value="0,1" id="hgt" /><br>
<input type="button" id="count" Value="Cell Count" />
</form>
<p>Results : <span id = "results"></span> </p>

<script> 
var num1 = document.getElementById("cell-count").value;
num2 = document.getElementById("box-count").value;
num3 = document.getElementById("dilution").value;
num4 = document.getElementById("lgh").value;
num5 = document.getElementById("wdh").value;
num6 = document.getElementById("hgt").value;
count = document.getElementById('count');
results = document.getElementById('results');

count.onclick = function(){
if(num1.value && num3.value && num4.value && num5.value && num6.value) {
var volume = num2 * ( num4 * num5 * num6 );
result_count = num1 / volume * num3;
results.innerHTML = funcRound(result_count);
} else {
results.innerHTML = "Please insert values";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code does not go as I expected, is there anything wrong with the code?

To be more clear what is my mistake, please help me here https://jsfiddle.net/atlm/06a2demh/

Please help.

Comment: please be clear about what errors are you getting, you can check from the console

Comment: Whats `num4` ?? Always use proper variable names!

Comment: @ShobiPP Please check here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/atlm/06a2demh/),

Comment: @JonasW.I tried with the name of another variable, but the same

Answer (score 1):

Fuzzyzilla address your issue. The code in your script tag is excuted when your page is loaded first. Therefore your num1.value, num3.value ... are all undefined, your  event handler doesn't reevaluate them before using them. 
From the beginning just console.log what you are doing or expecting to find where exactly things begin messing up !

Also the undefined result_count (initial is corrected ) ;

Comment: Thank you, But still confused with what you mean, please check here https://jsfiddle.net/atlm/06a2demh/

Comment: @KKoku Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are already taking `value` attribute from the element

`var num1 = document.getElementById("cell-count").value;`

Then again accessing the `value` attribute in this line :

`if(num1.value && num3.value && num4.value && num5.value && num6.value)`.

Instead just use:

`if(num1 && num3&& num4&& num5 && num6)`

Comment: Thank you, but still can not work, please check here https://jsfiddle.net/atlm/06a2demh/

Answer (score 0):

You're only gettin the values of the inputs once - you are not polling them each time the form is submitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Cell Count</title> 
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Cell Count : <input type="text" id="cell-count" /><br>
        Box Count : <input type="text" id="box-count" /><br>
        Dilution : <input type="text" id="dilution" /><br>
        Length : <input type="text" id="lgh" /><br>
        Width : <input type="text" id="wdh" /><br>
        Height : <input type="text" Value="0,1" id="hgt" /><br>
        <input type="button" id="count" Value="Cell Count" />
    </form>
    <p>Results : <span id = "results"></span> </p>

    <script> 
    count.onclick = function(){
        var cellCount = document.getElementById("cell-count").value,
            boxCount = document.getElementById("box-count").value,
            dilution = document.getElementById("dilution").value,
            length = document.getElementById("lgh").value,
            width = document.getElementById("wdh").value,
            height = document.getElementById("hgt").value,
            count = document.getElementById('count'),
            results = document.getElementById('results');


        if(cellCount && dilution && length && width && height) {
            var volume = boxCount * ( length * width * height );
            var result_count = (cellCount / volume) * dilution;
            results.innerHTML = funcRound(result_count);
        } else {
            results.innerHTML = "Please insert values";
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still can not work, please check here https://jsfiddle.net/atlm/06a2demh/